# SQL - Grouping data by the most recent updates

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, pivot, case

I have a problem with my queries (using SQL Developer). I have two tables PERSON and DEVICE.
PERSON (person_id, name)
DEVICE (device_id, person_id, device, version, udt)

Joined data looks like this:

[image]

However I want it to look like this:

[image]

So basically I want to have one row for each person and that row needs to have details of their different udt's with all the devices and the device that has been updated (udt) most recently (**Device_newest**) and the version of that (**Latest_version**).

I manage to come close with this query:

```
    select 
    PERSON.name, 
    max(case when SOFTWARE.device = 'mobile' then udt end) as mobile_udt,
    max(case when SOFTWARE.device = 'computer' then udt end) as computer_udt,
    max(case when SOFTWARE.device = 'laptop' then udt end) as laptop_udt
    
    from SOFTWARE
      left join PERSON on PERSON.person_id = SOFTWARE.person_id

    group by PERSON.name
```

but it doesn't have **Device_newest** and **Latest_version**. What should I do? I'm pretty sure that this is doable. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You may use the `PIVOT` clause (https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php). if you want i can write it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `keep` functionality in Oracle.  This is how Oracle implements a "first" aggregation function:

```
select p.name, 
       max(case when s.device = 'mobile' then udt end) as mobile_udt,
       max(case when s.device = 'computer' then udt end) as computer_udt,
       max(case when s.device = 'laptop' then udt end) as laptop_udt,
       max(s.device) keep (dense_rank first order by udt desc) as latest_device,
       max(s.version) keep (dense_rank first order by udt desc) as latest_version
from SOFTWARE s left join
     PERSON p 
     on p.person_id = a.person_id
group by p.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the PIVOT clause (techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php).
like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    select *
    from device
      left join PERSON on PERSON.person_id = device.person_id
)
PIVOT
(
  MAX(udt)
  FOR device IN ('mobile','computer','laptop')
)
ORDER BY name;
```

Comment: OP is already able to show those three columns but not the 4th and 5th.

Comment: thanks. That's right. I already get these max udt's but now I need also the informations from the newest udt device for each person.